# Macro is saved on Personal workbook but does not show up in Macro list

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007

I recorded a macro in Personal workbook, saved the file that I recorded with .xlsm. Then closed this workbook.
I assume that I can reuse this macro in other workbooks.
Next day I open a new work book trying to use the macro that I created yesterday. the Macro list/menu shows blank. the macro that i created yesterday is not there.

I tried to created a few ones, sames process but the new macros are not saved to use for new workbook. Can someone shed some light?
I use excel 2007

Comment: You should not save the PERSONAL.XLSB workbook as .XLSM and also it should ever be in the XLSTART directory. See https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Copy-your-macros-to-a-Personal-Macro-Workbook-aa439b90-f836-4381-97f0-6e4c3f5ee566?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Comment: @AxelRichter your link is not working. Perhaps http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/copy-your-macros-to-a-personal-macro-workbook-HA102174076.aspx] would be helpful.